# Nuget References. В Nuget есть, в References нет

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Добрый день, такая проблема, пакет в Nuget отображается галочкой, а в References его нет. В частности EntityFramework. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Покажите конкретно, что вы делаете. Из вашего описания сложно угадать, что вы сделали неправильно.

Comment: Удалил из References, потом решил вернуть назад, в итоге в References нет, а NugetManager отмечено что есть

Comment: Ну добавьте ссылку из того места, где nuget положил загруженный пакет. Откуда nuget'у знать, что вы удалили ссылку в проекте? Он отвечает лишь за наличие библиотеки в `packages`. Или если совсем неохота, уберите из nuget'а и снова добавьте, он вам снова добавит ссылку в проект.

Comment: @VladD оформите ответом что ли.

Comment: @andreycha: Сделал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно nuget складывает загруженные пакеты в каталог `packages` (но вы можете отконфигурировать это). Функциональность nuget и состоит в том, чтобы в `packages` был нужный пакет. Он не следит за тем, есть ли ссылка в вашем проекте, ему всё равно. Поэтому самым простым решением будет просто найти ваш пакет в `packages` и добавить ссылку на него снова, вручную.

При добавлении пакета через package manager (или package manager console) у вас происходит лёгкая магия: не только загружается пакет, но ещё ссылка на него добавляется в свойства вашего проекта. Поэтому если вам лень искать, где же лежит пакет, вы можете вызвать эту магию ещё раз: просто удалите пакет из package manager'а и добавьте его снова.

Comment: Хм. С одной стороны топикстартеру помогло, галку вижу. С другой стороны каких только граблей не бывает с референсами в проекте -- иногда приходится и вручную файлики проекта править в блокноте.

Comment: @AK: Ну да, приходится иногда. Но в данном случае по идее проблема более простая, и должна лечиться простым добавлением ссылки снова. Суть ответа — разделение ответственности между nuget (обеспечить наличие библиотеки) и файлом проекта (обеспечить подключение существующей библиотеки).